# Obter o resultado retornado ao Fazer F4

Tags: vba

Criei um VBA que mostra uma lista de fornecedores e não consigo obter o item selecionado após o F4.

```
Public Sub ListaFornecedores()
    Dim strSql As StdBEStringBuilder

    Set strSql = New StdBEStringBuilder

    strSql.Append ("SELECT Fornecedor, Nome FROM Fornecedores")
    PSO.Listas.GetF4SQL "Fornecedores", strSql.Value, "Fornecedor, Nome"

End Sub
```

Alguém sabe como retornamos o Item selecionado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tens de associar uma variavél ao resultado da função.
Neste caso vai devolver o Nome e Fornecedor separado por espaço.

```
Public Sub ListaFornecedores()
    Dim strSql As StdBEStringBuilder
    Dim strResultado as String

    Set strSql = New StdBEStringBuilder

    strSql.Append ("SELECT Fornecedor, Nome FROM Fornecedores")
    strResultado = PSO.Listas.GetF4SQL("Fornecedores", strSql.Value, "Fornecedor, Nome")

End Sub
```

Comment: Funcionou! Obrigado